# Which is the best among Visual Prolog, SWI-Prolog, and others?

Tags: prolog

I have searched the Internet and stackoverflow.com, but got nothing.

Who can give me a comparison between various Prolog compilers/IDEs such as Visual Prolog and SWI-Prolog?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've got two reasonable answers, but "best" questions usually don't get the kind of answers you are after.  What do you care about?  You mention Visual Prolog: does that mean you want to develop on Windows?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's hard to go wrong if you start with SWI-Prolog.  Although it is slower than most of the alternatives discussed here, it is extremely robust, has broad library support, has a decent GUI-building system (XPCE), and uses a license that allows its use in proprietary applications.

For better speed, it is a simple matter to convert most non-GUI SWI-Prolog applications to run under YAP Prolog.

Comment: also, it's actively developed, with 'best of class' techs in vital areas, like garbage collection

Comment: @CapelliC: SICStus has a complete and working GC since the 1980s. SWI got comparable GC only in 2009.

Comment: For compatibility with other systems, do not forget to call SWI7 with the option `-traditional`.

Answer (score 6):

If speed is the most important aspect, you should consider GNU-Prolog.  I recently developed using Amzi! Prolog with its Eclipse IDE (not to be confused with ECLiPSe programming language).  Once the debugging was done, I turned my attention to timing.  Porting to SWI-Prolog and GNU-Prolog was fairly straightforward, both on Windows and Linux, since at that point the code was fairly standard "ISO" Prolog.  My timings showed Amzi! and SWI were comparable in speed, and GNU-Prolog was significantly faster.

It also turned out the code was spending a large majority of time in one section that was very numeric.  While Amzi! and SWI both implement exact integer arithmetic in arbitrary precision, it turned out my requirements were just within the integer limits in 32-bit GNU-Prolog.

Moreover GNU-Prolog was easy to link to a rewrite of that critical section in C.  The hybrid code is what I'm using in production.

Comment: I've found YAP to be faster than GNU most of the time.

Comment: The new SICStus 4.3 has a native code JITTER. No extra declarations. Just in time.

Comment: Missing Unicode support draws it is mostly unusable for modern Web applications.

Comment: @AntonKochkov:  It is unclear to which of the various Prolog's mentioned in my Answer or in Comments above yours you impute a lack of Unicode support, or if perhaps you would like me to add a survey of Unicode support to my Answer.

Comment: @hardmath oh, sorry, I meant GNU Prolog still lacks proper Unicode support.

Answer (score 3):

You might get a good start by looking at [this comparison of Prolog implementations](http://www.fraber.de/university/prolog/comparison.html). Since you haven't made clear what your goals are, what platform you're targeting, what your requirements are, what your experience is, etc. there's not much more information I can provide.

---

*Edited to add:*

Wikipedia has a [good comparison chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Prolog_implementations) of Prolog implementations.  That should assist you in your decision making process.

Comment: @JUST, thank you very much for your help. My goal is integrating prolog engine into my application in static library. My application is written in C++.

Comment: @Just, My goal is platform-independent. Performance is important. My application is a real-time game.

Comment: Those comparisons left out [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org/features.html), and it advertises embed-ability. The [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECLiPSe)

Comment: Huh.  I'd never realized that ECLiPSe was a Prolog.  I thought it was its own (constraint) logic language.

Comment: @JUST: While it is true that Visual Prolog targets only Windows platforms, I don't think "for Win16" is accurate.  PDC describes it as Win32 code that works on Windows 32- or 64-bit platforms (XP, Vista, Win7).

Comment: @hardmath: I'm a bit out of date on Visual Prolog -- I hadn't realized they'd caught up to the Win32 world.

Comment: Wikipedia isn't very informed about Sicstus Prolog, which is pretty much the standard against which other Prolog implementations are to be judged.

Answer (score 1):

There is a performance based analysis of rule engines here:
http://sunysb.academia.edu/PaulFodor/Papers/349245/Openrulebench_An_Analysis_of_the_Performance_of_Rule_Engines

Im many tests, YAP seems to be in general the faster one, but XSB is not bad at all. If you are looking for inter-language communication (with Java, C, or others), database access, or tabling (these were my requirements), XSB has an impressive amount of sophisticated libraries.
However, I found YAP easier to use (until the present, I am just starting giving XSB a chance :).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Amzil Prolog because of it's GREAT Eclipse IDE Plugin. You'll find it here: [Official Site](http://www.amzi.com/).