# Why does strawberry prolog ignore whitespaces

Tags: prolog, ide

I'm using Strawberry Prolog and when I write

```
?- write('Hello World'),nl.
```

it outputs HelloWorld without whitespace but if I change the single quote to a double quote it outputs everything fine why is that?And why is this not a problem with other prolog IDE's?Also why is there a difference between single and double quotes?

Finally if it's no trouble can someone recommend a some guides on prolog?

Comment: *why is there a difference between single and double quotes?* That's just the way Prolog is defined. They actually mean different things. Single quotes define a single atom. Double quotes represents a list of character codes. Strawberry Prolog deleting spaces is strange and I don't know why they would do that. Strawberry Prolog would not be my first pick for a Prolog to use.

Comment: That is the prolog that my university uses.And thank you but which prolog would you recommend? and can you recommend some sort of documentation please?

Comment: SWI Prolog is arguably the most popular free version. GNU is good for more conservative ISO compliance. You could refer to this post: [Which is the best among Visual Prolog, SWI Prolog, and others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482783/which-is-the-best-among-visual-prolog-swi-prolog-and-others?rq=1)

Comment: I see can you recommend some good documentation?Thank you!

Comment: Go to the "Prolog" tag on this website, then click the "Info" tab. Eh.... here's the link: [Prolog info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good check point, for what a Prolog system should do, is always GNU Prolog (for some issues [version 1.3.0](https://gist.github.com/jburse/baa1a055a1e2fb28f4defa539b787d1c#gistcomment-2602657) is even better). It is very close to the ISO core standard, and doesn't have a lot of novelties. So you should get something along:

```
GNU Prolog 1.4.4 (64 bits)
Compiled Apr 23 2013, 16:05:07 with cl

?- write('Hello World'), nl.  
Hello World

yes
?- write("Hello World"), nl.  
[72,101,108,108,111,32,87,111,114,108,100]
```

**Explanation 1 Single Quotes:**

> The write/1 predicate should write
>   atoms unquoted. Which means atoms that usually need quotes, will be
>   written without quotes. If you want to show quotes you can use
>   writeq/1. And atom is in single quotes.

**Explanation 2 Double Quotes:**

> Double quotes were traditionally used
>   to denote lists of character codes, so that one can easily define DCG
>   rules. A lot of Prolog systems divert here, and even the ISO core
>   standard allows character atoms instead codes.

But usually you can ask the Prolog system what it does with double quotes, and even modify the behaviour. Just use the Prolog flag double_quotes. Here is what you can do in GNU-Prolog:

```
?- current_prolog_flag(double_quotes, X).  
X = codes

?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).  
yes

?- write("Hello World"), nl.  
[H,e,l,l,o, ,W,o,r,l,d]
```